# Need help modifying a linked list in C

Tags: c, list, nodes

I have a linked list structure with values 6 5 4 3 in order. I need to subtract 1 from each term so that I have a new node with value 5 4 3 2. I don't know how you would do this because if I use a simple code such as.

```
while(node != NULL){
   node->value = (node->value) -1;
   node = node->next;
 }
return node;
```

However this returns nothing because I'm essentially erasing any modifications I make. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: *...I'm essentially erasing any modifications I make...*?. What do you mean by that. The modifications are made properly and will reflect later.

Comment: "I'm essentially erasing any modifications I make" What makes you think so? The typical issue that you don't update a linked list when modifying the list head applies to data that is external to the list, nemaly the head pointer, which isn't held by any node. Here, the data should be updated as expected.

Comment: `Type ret = node; while(node != NULL){ ... } return ret;`

Comment: When I go to print the node nothing prints however before putting it through this subtract function it does print fine. Doesn't this code erase the entire node because you modify the head but then set the head to the next term?

Comment: Provide the entire code, so that we can look into what exactly is happening

Comment: @BLUEPIXIE has it. (Good catch, I didn't see it!) If you are only changing the contents of the nodes, there is no need to update the head pointer, so your function could as well be `void`.